# How to get domain user SIDs from local machine when enumerating local group membership

Tags: windows, wmi, wmi-query

I am enumerating a local group on Windows domain-joined machines. I'm using WMI to do this as it is very remote & supply-credentials friendly. In my scenario my code is always running remotely and as an untrusted principal which means I *must* be able to supply credentials in the remote call to the target computer (this sounds random but is actually related later on).

I'm doing a WMI query of the form:

```
SELECT PartComponent FROM Win32_GroupUser WHERE GroupComponent="Win32_Group.Domain='{0}',Name='{1}'"
```

Domain in this case is the computer name and name is the name of the group itself.

The list of items I get back is correct, but each entry lacks the SID of the principal in question. What's the most efficient way to get SIDs for these users?

I could do this via another query for each principal (or obvious optimizations over this), which I'd be happy to do for local users on this box. However, for domain users, this means another connection to a DC in the domain in which this principal resides, and potentially many of them given that there could be users from many trusted domains in this local group.

I looked at some of the obvious other APIs but didn't spot one that was super friendly to my cause. Some, like using DirectoryEntry() with a path of the form WinNT://ComputerName/GroupName,Group event went so far as to emit returning domain principals from the results, which I found wild. Others are not supply credentials friendly even though they return the group membership data I'm after.

Truth be told, I'd be perfectly happy with just SIDs. Principal names and domain names, while I find them very convenient, are nice to have for me.

Is there a silver bullet for this that I'm missing?